# LimeSurvey - choosing which pstpl will be displayed

Tags: php, limesurvey

I dont know where to find the function, or object which is responsible for selection which pstpl will be displayed on "Welcome Page".

In admin/templates.php I have found varialbes which defines pstpl visible in theme editor in admin panel. But it is all, what I have found.

Answer (score 0):

You know welcom.pstpl is shown, the use grep to find where

```
$ grep -r 'welcome.pstpl' *
application/controllers/admin/templates.php:            'welcome.pstpl',
application/controllers/admin/templates.php:            'welcome.pstpl',
application/helpers/frontend_helper.php:    echo templatereplace(file_get_contents($sTemplateViewPath."welcome.pstpl"),array(),$redata,'frontend_helper[2762]')."\n";
application/helpers/SurveyRuntimeHelper.php:                echo templatereplace(file_get_contents($sTemplateViewPath."welcome.pstpl"), array(), $redata) . "\n";
application/config/internal.php:            'excludeFiles' => array("config.xml", "assessment.pstpl", "clearall.pstpl",  "completed.pstpl",  "endgroup.pstpl",  "endpage.pstpl",  "groupdescription.pstpl",  "load.pstpl",  "navigator.pstpl",  "printanswers.pstpl",  "print_group.pstpl",  "print_question.pstpl",  "print_survey.pstpl",  "privacy.pstpl",  "question.pstpl",  "register.pstpl",  "save.pstpl",  "startgroup.pstpl",  "startpage.pstpl",  "surveylist.pstpl",  "survey.pstpl",  "welcome.pstpl" ),
```

Then : in application/helpers/SurveyRuntimeHelper.php and application/helpers/frontend_helper.php for public views .

Next time : you don't need to ask, but use grep :)